# Can't display Chinese characters in Python when reading a JSON file with UTF-8 encoding, any solutions?

Tags: python, json, utf-8

I am working on a json file with Chinese words in it. I try to read it in my machine with Python, but the Chinese characters just can't be correctly displayed. Here is the json file(a.json):

```
{
  "squadName": "哈囉",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import json

storage = []
with open('a.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
```

Here is the output:

```
{'squadName': '���o', 'homeTown': 'Metro City', 'formed': 2016, 'secretBase': 'Super tower', 'active': True}
```

Everything works properly except for the Chinese characters
Does anyone know how to fix it?

I've searched so many solutions and I also set the 'encoding' parameter to `utf-8` or `utf-8-sig`, but it still not working.

Comment: Have you confirmed the encoding of the json file? Maybe its not utf-8.

Comment: What python version are you using ?

Comment: If this is an input encoding problem, we need to see the actual encoded bytes from the input JSON. However, the answer you got about an _output_ encoding problem seems like a better speculation with the information you have provided (and is a very common FAQ to boot; the simplest answer is "don't use Windows" but since that is unacceptable to many beginners, there is a plethora of workarounds). See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine. However, you need to ensure that your output handler is capable of properly displaying these characters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need to fix anything. Your code is just fine.

As you can see below:

(this is Pycharm IDE)
[image]

(CMD terminal)
[image]

Comment: so you mean the problem comes from the display of my terminal(machine)?

Comment: perhaps, it shows the data as expected even if I run it from the CMD terminal.

Comment: If the question is not reproducible, please don't post an answer. Just vote to close as "typo or not reproducible".